# Help with question involving counting passwords (sum and product rule)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Each user on a computer system has a password, which is either seven or eight characters long, where each character is an uppercase letter or digit. Each password must contain at least one digit. How many possible passwords are there?

Solution: $$P=(36^7-26^7)+(36^8-26^8)$$

Important Note: I am not asking about how to solve this question. I want to know in the process of getting the solution, why can't I subtract $10^7$ (the number of passwords that consist of only digits) from $36^7$ (number of passwords consisting of both digits and letters)? and the same with $10^8$ and $36^8$ respectively, why can't I subtract the two?

When I do subtract $10^7$ and $10^8$ from the two, I get a different answer which is a very large number, $2.899999e^{12}$, something like that, but with the actual solution it is something around $2.682e^{12}$.

TL;DR  Why do I have to subtract $26^7$ and $26^8$ from $36^7$ and $36^8$ respectively, instead of subtracting $10^7$ and $10^8$ from $36^7$ and $36^8$?

Comment: What is the reason of downvoting this question?..

Answer (score 1):

Note that the assignment says that password must contain at least one digit, and can therefore not consist of letters only. Subtracting $10^7$ and $10^8$ would mean eliminating cases where the password contains digits only, which are valid passwords. Instead, you have to subtract $26^7$ and $26^8$, because these are the number of passwords that contain only letters. Indeed, the total number of passwords equals:

$$36^8 + 36^7 - 26^8 - 26^7 \approx 2.68 \cdot 10^{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you start with all passwords without further conditions then to find the passwords that contain at least one digit to be subtracted are all passwords that have no digits (i.e. the passwords that only contain lower case letters).

In short "number of all passwords minus the number of passwords that do not satisfy the condition".